# Count regex in file

Tags: c++, strings, regex

I have a task to search regex in many files.

How do you think is this code optimal by performance and complexity?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
 std::ifstream input;
 std::string line;
 input.open("test.ws");
 std::getline(input,line);
 line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(),line.end(),ispunct),line.end());
 std::regex reg(argv[1]);
 std::ptrdiff_t const matchCn (std::distance(std::sregex_iterator(line.begin(),line.end(),reg),std::sregex_iterator()));
 std::cout << matchCn;
}
```

I'm trying to use STL for count number of regex in `string` getting from file.

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::ifstream input;
  input.open("test.ws");
```

Prefer to acquire resources/responsibilities on initialization (see RAII) instead of lazy initialization.  Constructors exist to define the class invariants, so use them to create fully initialized objects.

If the file cannot be opened for whatever reason, you should notify the user that an error occurred. Validate your post-conditions.

---

```
  line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(),line.end(),ispunct),line.end());
```

If you are simply searching, is there a reason for stripping away punctuation?

`ispunct` requires `<cctype>`.

---

```
  std::regex reg(argv[1]);
```

Did the user provide `argv[1]`? Validate your preconditions.

Was the regex pattern a valid expression? `std::regex` throws `std::regex_error` if the provided expression is invalid.  You should catch it and notify the user failure occurred.

---

> I have a task to search regex in many files.

The code you have provided will not accomplish this task.  I was going to report it as not ready to be reviewed, but it has up-votes.